# Equation of a line passing through a given point, perpendicular with a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the line that goes through A(1,0,2) and is perpendicular to 
r = (-2,3,4) + s (1,1,2)

I did a bunch of work, but I don't know if any of it is right. I erased most of it, but this is what I came up with, which is wrong. Answer is: r = (1,0,2) + t(-11,7,2)

my work: 
[image: My work]

Comment: mind sharing some of that work?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You mean perpendicular to $[1,1,2]^T$ through A(1,0,2)? There are an infinite number of such lines, which span a plane. Are there any other conditions?

Comment: I think the issue is that the problem wants you to find the perpendicular line through point $ \ A \ $ that _extends_ from some point on the line given by $ \ \vec{r} \ $ .  The "dot product" of your direction vector with the direction for $ \ \vec{r} \ $ is certainly zero, but your line is skew to $ \ \vec{r} \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: what do you mean by "your line is skew ..." ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo  You have basically provided the method I was going to describe (once it was morning here again).  What I was saying it that while the two direction vectors OP gave _are_ perpendicular, there was no value of the parameters that equated _all_ of the coordinates at once.  So the lines were not intersecting.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: From my computation the lines are incident in (-8/3,7/3,8/3) for s=-2/3 and t=1/3.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo OK, I'm getting that to work _now_ (I shouldn't try to do arithmetic at 3 AM...).  Thanks -- I thought the source of OP's difficulty was that the constructed perpendicular line wasn't meeting the line $ \ \vec{r} \ $ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vector from A to the generic point $(-2+s,3+s,4+2s)$ of $r$ and equal the dot product of this and $(1,1,2)$ to $0$.
Found the value of $s$, substitute in the above vector: rescale if you want $(-11,7,2)$, every other parallel vector is good.